# Swagger same DateTime field Format different between Request and Response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

We have StartDate and endDate field in the Model with the datatype of DateTime.
Swagger **POST** PayLoad json the default value of date is containing ***Z*** at the end.
[image]

But the same field displaying in **GET** Request as response without ***Z***.
[image]

Could you please let me know any Swagger configuration need to be done from my end.

Comment: No , you don't have to worry about that. Z at the end of data represents universal sortable date https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.universalsortabledatetimepattern?view=net-8.0.

Comment: Are you using swashbuckle or nswag to generate the swagger-ui from your API?

Comment: I'm using swashbuckle to generate swagger-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please let me know any Swagger configuration need to be done from my end.

This is unlikely a *Swagger configuration* issue.

The date-time value returned in the response are not valid according to RFC3339, which is the standard for internet dates which OpenAPI implements. To be valid according to this standard, a time-zone component must be included in a date-time value. From [RFC3339 section 5.6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3339#section-5.6),

> full-time = partial-time **time-offset**

The time-zone component is either a *Z* to indicate UTC time-zone, or it is an offset plus or minus some whole number of hours and minutes, for example *+03:00*.

My guess would be that the OpenAPI specification which enables Swagger UI to generate the examples in your Swagger UI screengrabs contains a schema definition for the fields *startDate* and *endDate* in the response that doesn't restrict them to only allowing date-time formatted values.

OpenAPI implements JsonSchema for type defintions, and according to the [JsonSchema *date-time* format directive](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string#dates-and-times),

> Dates and times are represented in RFC 3339, section 5.6.

So, if you modify the definition of these fields in the OpenAPI specification to properly reflect the fact that they are date-time restricted, then once you have also updated the examples within the specification, Swagger UI should display these values correctly.

For example,

```
components:
  schemas:
    MyResponseBody:
      type: object
      properties:
        startDate: 
          type: string
          format: date-time # <-- restricts values to internet date/time format
          example: 2024-02-16T17:28:51.595Z # <-- add the "Z" suffix to any examples
        endDate: 
          type: string
          format: date-time 
          example: 2024-02-16T17:28:51.595Z
```

Comment: Please let me know which file I have to configure this change in Asp.net Core like startup.cs or any swagger json

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ - it will be the swagger.json file I think